# mysql - regex - rlike with 1 and without 10

Tags: mysql, regex, rlike

I've got a mysql table with the following data:

```
ID | Name
1 | xy 
4 | dasd
9 | 422p
10 | dasös
```

and I've got the following query which should display only the values "1 and 4", but it displays 1,4,10.

```
rlike '1|^4'
```

any idea?

Comment: This may be only due to your choice of example data, but why would you use `RLIKE` for this rather than `IN(1,4)`?  If you in fact have more complicated row data, it would help if you posted a more representative example.

Comment: I'll need your help with the following code. If there is no tickets with the prio_id 5 it should be displayed "ok" and when there one or more tickets with an higher priority it should be a image displayed

    <?php 
    $alert = mysql_query("SELECT count(tn) AS Prio-Tickets FROM ticket where ticket_state_id = 1 AND    ticket_priority_id = 5;");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($alert)){
    if ($row->Prio-Tickets = 0 )
    {
    echo 'OK';
    } else { 
    echo '<img src="alert.gif"/>'
    }} 
    ?>

Comment: This being unrelated to your existing question here, you need to ask it as a new question rather than expand the old one to a very different scope in the comment thread.

Comment: Please tell exactly what you want to achieve, as if its 4, 1, 40 then what should be the output ?

Comment: You may use MySQL REGEX as well:     SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '^[1,4]$'

Answer (score 0):

If you insistence for use `RLIKE`, You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` RLIKE '^1$|^4$';
```

See online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0ede/1/0

But better then and more efficient and more principled and faster then is use `IN`, be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` IN (1, 4);
```

See online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0ede/2/0

Thanks